# Как сделать таблицу с операциями?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытаюсь написать функцию, которая принимает в качестве аргумента функцию, вычисляющую элемент по номеру строки и столбца.Плюс к таблице умножения еще и таблица сложения, а также таблица возведения в степень.

```
def printOperationTable(operation, numRows=9, numColumns=9):
    if operation(1,1)==2:
        print(1,end='\t')

    for row in range(1, numRows+1):
        for column in range(1, numColumns+1):
            if operation(1,1)==2:
                column=column-1
            print(operation(row,column), end='\t')
        print()
```

Аргументы `numRows` и `numColumns` указывают число строк и столбцов таблицы, которые должны быть распечатаны. Нумерация строк и столбцов идёт с единицы.

**Формат ввода:**

```
print(printOperationTable(lambda x,y: x∗y, 2, 3))
```

**Формат *желаемого* вывода:**

```
1   2   3  
2   4   6
```

**Формат вывода:**

```
1   2   3   
2   4   6   
None
```

При тестировании "таблицы сложения" все столбцы съезжают влево:

```
1   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  
3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  
4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  
5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  
6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  
7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  
8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  
9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  
None
```

При тестировании "таблицы степеней" первая строчка состоит из единиц:

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
2   4   8   16  32  64  128 256 512 
3   9   27  81  243 729 2187    6561    19683   
4   16  64  256 1024    4096    16384   65536   262144  
5   25  125 625 3125    15625   78125   390625  1953125 
6   36  216 1296    7776    46656   279936  1679616 10077696    
7   49  343 2401    16807   117649  823543  5764801 40353607    
8   64  512 4096    32768   262144  2097152 16777216    134217728   
9   81  729 6561    59049   531441  4782969 43046721    387420489   
None
```

**Основные проблемы:**

1. `None` во всех видах таблиц
2. "Съезд" столбцов в таблице сложения
3. Не правильная первая строка в таблице степеней

Answer (score 1):

Вашу функцию можно изменить так:

```
from math import log10

def printOperationTable(operation, numRows=9, numColumns=9):
    if operation(1,1)==2:
        print(1,end='\t')

    colSize = int(log10(operation(numRows+1, numColumns+1)))+2

    for row in range(1, numRows+1):
        for column in range(1, numColumns+1):
            if operation(1,1)==2:
                column=column-1
            print("{:>{}}".format(operation(row,column), colSize), end='\t')
        print()
```

А печатать таблицу просто вызовом функции, так как печать происходит внутри функции, а функция ничего не возвращает

```
printOperationTable(lambda x,y: x*y, 10, 10)
```

Comment: А без ввода параметра `colSize` обойтись нельзя? Это идёт вразрез данному заданию...

Comment: поправил, сделал вычисление  colSize внутри функции

Answer (score 0):

```
def printOperationTable(operation, numRows=9, numColumns=9):
    for row in range(1, numRows+1):
        for column in range(1, numColumns+1):
            print(operation(row,column), end='\t')
        print()
```